# UNHANDLED REJECTION Failed to process image

Tags: reactjs, shopify, gatsby, sharp

I am using gatsby-shopify-starter. Ran gatsby develop command. This starter is giving this error while processing some of images that are fetched from shopify and when processing reaches following : 
⠴ run static queries — 2/3 1.66 queries/second
[==                          ]   9.087 s 1/13 8% Generating image thumbnail 
I get UNHANDLED REJECTION Failed to process image C:/Users/user_name/my_store/.cache/gatsby-source-filesystem/0a123343546767888cc90.jpg

Tried clearing the cache and deleting cache folder

Expect it to start the gatsby server on local machine without errors

Answer (score -1):

I could resolve this error by running gatsby new command again.